# Best way to share content between a Wordpress site and a Drupal site

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, reverse-proxy, drupal-modules

I will try to be clear but if you need more information please do not hesitate.

A site approached me to make a partnership together. They want to create a new section on their site, say a "blog" section. The goal is to post my blog post on their site, in this new section, without having access to their admin.

So I need to set up something to be able to automatically share the content I post on my site with their site. My site is on Wordpress and their site is on Drupal.

For now I see 2 possibilities, but tell me what you think and if there is better to do.

- First possibility: Create the page /blog and all the articles (ex: /blog/article-title) on my site, then set up a reverse proxy to redirect their request to my server. I have no experience with network setup so maybe I am completely wrong. But even if it works, I don't know how to fetch only post content (not header, footer) and change all urls.
- Second possibility: Create a Drupal module, which they will have to install on their site, which creates the page /blog and the custom content type named "blog" when it is activated. And then use the feeds module to get the content from my wordpress feed and create a blog post for each post in the feed. With this solution, I won't have any header or footer problem, and the urls to the articles will be generated dynamically.

Every advice will be usefull. Thank you.

Comment: RSS is a ready to go solution so i would keep it simple. Check this - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/aggregator/overview . Wordpress provides different feeds so you can go any routh - https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/ .

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the easiest way to do that is to use the Wordpress REST API.

You could get all posts with this `https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` and get a specific post with `https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/:id`

full doc here : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the second possibility, cause there are already several drupal moduls in the wild the read and import feeds from other sites.

Even more, WordPress will provide your posts also in oembed-format. With this you can use this Drupal Modul: https://www.drupal.org/project/soembed

You vcan adjust this modul to allow content from your website and display it on the Drupal installation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).